# How to make a jQuery effects works for infinite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

how can I make the effect in jQuery works for infinite and won't stop, Since when I run it right now, it works only for a couple of seconds(3 sec) & stop after that.

ex:

```
$('div').effect('Slide');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){$('div').effect('slide')}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(function looper(){
  // use callback function of the effect to call the outer looper function recursively.
  $('div').effect('Slide', function(){
    setTimeout(looper, 25); // add a timeout of needed
  });
})();
```